# Как заставить расширение для хрома работать только на определенных страницах?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, расширения, google-chrome-devtools

Мне нужно чтобы расширение работало только на страницах с .example.com и на локальных страницах. Не могу понять как это сделать, сейчас работает на всех.

manifets.json

```
  {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "name": "Test helper",
      "description": "Помощник для тестирования",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
          "js": ["jquery.min.js", "main.js" ],
          "css": ["css/style.css"]
        }
      ],
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"]
    }
```

background.js

```
// Wrap in an onInstalled callback in order to avoid unnecessary work
// every time the background script is run
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  // Page actions are disabled by default and enabled on select tabs
  chrome.action.disable();

  // Clear all rules to ensure only our expected rules are set
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
    // Declare a rule to enable the action on example.com pages
    let exampleRule = {
      conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {hostSuffix: '.example.com'},
        })
      ],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()],
    };

    // Finally, apply our new array of rules
    let rules = [exampleRule];
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules(rules);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил это удалив бэкграунд и добавив в манифест

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.example.com/","http://127.0.0.1/*","file:///*"],
    }
  ],
```